What is the meaning of array index [fp+0] in awk example?
At this page https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/More-CSV.html, have this example to work on awk with csv files.
The example works very well!
But, I couldn't understand the fpat+0 on this code:
BEGIN {
     fp[0] = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
     fp[1] = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
     fp[2] = "([^,]*)|(\"([^\"]|\"\")+\")"
     FPAT = fp[fpat+0]
}

What that means?

Consider using strongly typed regexp constants for this instead of dynamic regexps for efficiency and conciseness in writing the regexps, e.g. dynamic regexp fp[2] = "([^,]*)|(\"([^\"]|\"\")+\")" can be written as strongly typed regexp constant fp[2] = @/([^,]*)|("([^"]|"")+")/ without all the escapes before "s.

From OP's link we see how the gawk script is called:
$ gawk -v fpat=2 -f test-csv.awk sample.csv

What happens if user provides no -v fpat=... clause?
In (g)awk adding a zero to an undefined variable (eg, fpat+0) will generate a 0:
$ awk 'BEGIN {print fpat+0}'
0

Regarding the referenced gawk code, when fpat+0 generates a 0 we end up using fp[0] as the default pattern.
